# How to fix insufficientLivePermissions while Creating youtube live streaming event

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I get the exception bellow when I create a Live Stream Event

```
    {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "insufficientLivePermissions",
        "message": "Request is not authorized",
        "extendedHelp": "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert#auth_required"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request is not authorized"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have permission to do live videos.

Check the link for more info.
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2474026?hl=en-GB

Link also shows you how to check if you have live streaming enabled.

This link will list the features enabled on your youtube channel.

https://www.youtube.com/features

Mine says live streaming eligible and embed live stream ineligible. Probably because i haven't enabled them.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. 
Check as follows.

You should create broadcast manually. 
I got a message "You are creating too many live streams. Please wait a while before creating further streams."

Is there anybody can solve this problem? I have to create many events in a short period. Is there any white list? or Business youtube account?